# When doing a ROPE analysis for dichotomous predictors what kind of coding should I use?

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-model, stan

I am using stan_lmer() to run a mixed effects analysis. The key variable I am interested in testing for the ROPE is an interaction between two dichotomous predictors. I understand that the scale of this coefficient will vary depending on whether they are dummy coded or effects coded, and that this will affect the percentage falling in the ROPE. I am using rope() to handle that calculation, setting `ci = 1`.

What is best practice re: effects coding vs dummy coding the variables?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any best practice around this. I would have thought that it's just a re-parameterisation of the same model - so the interpretation will be different, that's all

Comment: @RobertLong Thanks Robert. I just experimented with leaving the predictor as dummy coded vs effects coding it (`contrasts(d$Congruent) <- c(-1, 1)`). They do indeed show different results, so I'm not sure which is more accurate.

Comment: Neither is more accurate - it's just a different parameterisation of the same model.

Comment: @RobertLong So if one gives a clear result (i.e., >95% of posterior in ROPE) but another doesn't (i.e., 80% of posterior in ROPE), what's the best course of action? Report both?